# OpenGL not supporting GLSL 3.30 with intel 4000 graphics and Mesa 11

Tags: ubuntu, opengl, intel, opengl-3, mesa

Hello I'm having a bit of a problem getting a shader to compile with my Intel laptop (i5-3317U -> HD 4000) on Ubuntu 15.04

The log info from `glGetShaderInfoLog` says

```
error: GLSL 3.30 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.00 ES, and 3.00 ES
```

According to mesa 11 I should be able to run 3.30 (www.mesa3d.org/shading.html) and from what I understand my system should be able to handle these shaders.

So does anyone know what the issue may be? Is it time for me to get a new system??

by the way if it helps the results from running `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` on my system is

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 11.1.0-devel (git-d6a41b5 2015-09-27 vivid-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 11.1.0-devel (git-d6a41b5 2015-09-27 vivid-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 11.1.0-devel (git-d6a41b5 2015-09-27 vivid-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a compatibility or core context?

Comment: Create a core profile, then it will work.